# What does direct query to live connection model technically mean?

Tags: powerbi

I have published a power bi report to Power BI service (the pbix file contains report and dataset [import mode, pointing to SQL server and refreshed via on prem gateway]).

Next I create a new report by pointing to the above, and this is called LIVE connection.

Support I convert this report into a composite model (by adding an Excel data source), then I see that the live connection gets converted into direct query mode.

Direct query usually means query goes to the source SQL server. What does direct query to live dataset mean?

Answer (score 1):

Live connection is similar to DQ, but when using Live connection, there is no data model in Power BI at all (there is no PowerQuery layer between the visualization layer and the data source) and the one from the data source is used instead. That's why only SSAS, AAS and Power BI datasets are supported as a data source in this case.

DirectQuery for Power BI Datasets and Analysis Services includes the metadata for the data, like a DirectQuery connection for any other data source. This model can be changed (extended, combined with data from other data sources, etc.), which is not possible when using Live connection, because the underlying model is reused in this case.

When using Live connection, DAX queries are sent to the Analysis Services engine. When using DirectQuery, Power BI's formula engine takes care for them.

In case of DirectQuery to a Power BI dataset, which has data from SQL Server imported, the data will be read from this dataset and it will not go to the underlying SQL Server. DQ in this case means, that the data source (the intermediate Power BI dataset between your report and the SQL Server) will be used for the queries, like the case with Live connection to it. The difference is which engines will be used - in your report or in the intermediate dataset.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your report to the service you upload a dataset and a report. If you make another report with a direct query connection to that dataset. It will query your report on the dataset that you have uploaded to the microsoft Power BI Service.

For instance, if you add a measure to your import model and then upload the new version to the service. Your direct query model will also contain this new measure. Each visual will query straight from the published dataset instead of a downloaded dataset.

Comment: So that means it's still a live connection. No?